# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try to post any thing that contains `<whatever>` I get

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form
>   value was detected from the client
>   Description: Request Validation has
>   detected a potentially dangerous
>   client input value, and processing of
>   the request has been aborted. This
>   value may indicate an attempt to
>   compromise the security of your
>   application, such as a cross-site
>   scripting attack. To allow pages to
>   override application request
>   validation settings, set the
>   requestValidationMode attribute in the
>   httpRuntime configuration section to
>   requestValidationMode="2.0". Example:
>   . After
>   setting this value, you can then
>   disable request validation by setting
>   validateRequest="false" in the Page
>   directive or in the 
>   configuration section. However, it is
>   strongly recommended that your
>   application explicitly check all
>   inputs in this case. For more
>   information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=153133.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException:
>   A potentially dangerous Request.Form
>   value was detected from the client

I have following asp.net code

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="newsDetail" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceNews"
                AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="id" 
                OnItemUpdating="NewsDetailItemUpdating" OnItemCreated="NewsDetailItemCreated"
                OnItemDeleted="NewsDetailItemDeleted" OnItemInserted="NewsDetailItemInserted"
                OnItemInserting="NewsDetailItemInserting" OnItemUpdated="NewsDetailItemUpdated"
                DefaultMode="Insert">

                <Fields>
                    <asp:TemplateField FooterText="show at statpage" HeaderText="view" SortExpression="view">
                       ...
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="headline" HeaderText="Headline" SortExpression="headline">
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Text">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="post" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("post") %>' OnPreRender="PostLabelPreRender" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="postTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("post") %>' TextMode="MultiLine"
                                Width="500px" Height="300px" />
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="postTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("post") %>' TextMode="MultiLine"
                                Width="500px" Height="300px" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

And the code

```
    protected void NewsDetailItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        // Iterate though the values entered by the user and HTML encode 
        // the values. This helps prevent malicious values from being 
        // stored in the data source.
        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewValues.Count; i++)
            if (e.NewValues[i] != null)
                e.NewValues[i] = Server.HtmlEncode(e.NewValues[i].ToString());
    }

    protected void NewsDetailItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Values.Count; i++)
            if (e.Values[i] != null)
                e.Values[i] = Server.HtmlEncode(e.Values[i].ToString());
    }

    protected void NewsDetailItemUpdated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        newsList.DataBind();
    }

    protected void NewsDetailItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
    {
        newsList.DataBind();
    }

    protected void NewsDetailItemDeleted(object sender, DetailsViewDeletedEventArgs e)
    {
        newsList.DataBind();
    }

    protected void NewsDetailItemCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newsList.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to post HTML / Javascript as the content of one of your text boxes?

Comment: I was going to tag this as a duplicate, but then I wasn't sure which of the 15 duplicates to pick...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem you're having is that in one of your text boxes you have put html tags or just the < > symbols and the .net framework tracks that as a potential dangerous script.  This is to prevent people from putting malicious script tags in the input fields.

You can work around this by putting in your page directive `ValidateRequest="false"` you will also have to put in your web.config `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" ... />`

Comment: There's also the option of encoding pre-submission, to help ensure that none of the content passed back to the server is malicious.

Comment: I'm use the Server.HtmlEncode, so I do not think I should get this error. Am I using it wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll still be posting back the potentially dangerous content before the server is able to encode it.  And, thinking through my previous comment, you'll never to guarantee that the content coming back has actually been encoded (disabling JS, etc.).  So the right way probably is disabling validation for this page specifically, and making sure you encode everything entered on this page on output.

Comment: @IanPugsley could you elaborate on why you cant guarantee the encoding? Is there any other safe workaround for this error that you know of?

Answer (score 2):

Try this web.config file In 
add or set httpRuntime requestValidationMode as

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```